# Mercurial partial clone in subrepository or guestrepo

Tags: svn, mercurial, svn-externals, mercurial-subrepos, hgsubversion

Is it possible to do a partial clone of a mercurial repository as either a subrepository or a guestrepo?

## description:

given a repo at `https://blah/hg/foo/` named `foo` and another repo named `cat` , I'd like to create a guestrepo in `cat` from a certain directory under `foo`, eg. from `c` in `foo:/a/b/c/`.

To my best knowledge `c` is not available as a stand-alone repository. Read-only access to `foo` is assumed.

My intent is to have `cat:/d/e/c/`, the guest location, update if `foo:/a/b/c/` changes. This is considered to be similar behavior to `svn:externals` in `svn`.

## GuestrepoExtension:

I started out with trying the [GuestrepoExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/GuestrepoExtension):

`.hggrmapping`:

```
c = https://blah/hg/foo
```

`.hgguestrepo`:

```
/d/e/c/ = ??? ???
```

The problem is I don't know how to reference the sub-directory given that I don't need the whole `foo` repository, only this directory and it's contents from it.

According to https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PartialClone partial cloning / cloning of subdirectories is not implemented in mercurial (referred [Bug 105](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/bts/issue105) is already closed since 2012). This is why,

## Subrepository:

Currently I resorted to using a [subrepository](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository) since coincidentally the `c` directory exists in an svn mirror.

.hgsub:

```
/d/e/c = [svn]https://dog/svn/a/b/c/
```

This has the drawback that I don't want to rely on external version control, ie. `svn`, repository and tool availability.

Could this be handled somehow purely in mercurial?

Comment: There's the [NarrowHG extension](https://bitbucket.org/Google/narrowhg), but that requires that the remote repository also has it installed.

Comment: More tricky, but obvious way - convert `c/` dir to separate repo, link it to both `foo` (remove original c/) and `cat`